# How to click a particular side of a BoxGeometry in THREE.js?

Tags: three.js

I'd like to be able to get the coordinates of a particular side of a BoxGeometry to be able to click on it programatically. Say the top side of the BoxGeometry versus the left side or right side. I'm able to grab the object's position and convert from world coordinates but unsure to get particular sides.

Comment: I didn't post an answer because I don't have time to write a full answer with example code, but:

The raycasting answer is correct. The way to make your life way easier though is to use 6 planes with names like "top" or "left". Then use raycasting and check `intersects[0].object.name`.

Comment: Mark as duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50360903/how-to-detect-what-side-of-a-cube-is-clicked

Comment: You can start with exploring the source code of [`THREE.BoxGeometry()`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/2f2e5f73181e7e3e1a845ab5d9c67192cb1e16e4/src/geometries/BoxGeometry.js#L79) to know what side where is.

Answer (score 1):

You want to do a raycast. You make a ray from the cursor position, do the raycast, and get back a list of all the things that ray hit, in order of distance along the ray.. The first element will have a pointer to the cube, and the index or a pointer to the face that was hit.. cubes are made of 2 triangles per face, you if you divide the face index by 2, that should give you back a face.. 0 thru 5.. OR you can look at the hit normal.. which will be like 1,0,0  -1,0,0   0,1,0  0,-1,0  or 0,0,1 0,0,-1 depending on the facing of the surface at the ray hit point.

https://threejs.org/examples/?q=rayca#webgl_geometry_terrain_raycast

edit:

The cognitive stumbling block here is that what you are thinking of as a "face" of the cube is actually 2 faces.. (2 triangles).. so you will have to impose your own structure if you want to deal with the square faces as a single entity.. so if triangle1 OR triangle2 is hit.. then that is just cube face 1... one way to identify faces that are on the same plane, is by looking at their face normals. Faces on the same plane will have face normals that are very similar, if not identical. like.. 1,0,0 for triangles facing right, and -1,0,0 for triangles facing left... 0,1,0 for triangles facing up, 0,-1,0 for triangles facing down, and 0,0,1 for triangles facing away, and 0,0,-1 for triangles facing toward you... Does that make sense?

So if you get a ray hit.. look at the hit[0].face.normal and check the sign/x/y/z to find which cube "face" that triangle belongs to...

Comment: Yes, I know about the faces that the intersection provides via the raycaster but still not sure how I can know the position of that face in the world.

Comment: You can take the resulting face vertices from the raycast, and transform them by the cubes matrixWorld to get world coordinates.. or if you want the whole cube in world coordinates, loop through its geometry.vertices and vertex.clone().applyMatrix4(cube.matrixWorld) the verts.

Comment: Interesting! So, if I were to provide a function where I could want to automatically click a particular side of a cube, I'd get the faces and convert them to worldCoordinates and then click that particular face?